# Can we remove the references to Win9x and Win NT 4 from the Neo4jShell.BAT file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, neo4j

The Neo4jShell.BAT file in the Neo4j distribution has logic etc. for Windows 95/98/NT4.  Do we really need this anymore? I would not have thought Neo4j is even supported on these operating systems.

Having this logic in there makes the batch file unnecessarily complicated.  Also the environment variable checks are case sensitive and if they fail, it defaults to Windows 95/98

Would you accept a Pull Request to remove this logic and simplify the Shell script?

Comment: This question should go on their github page, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yep I think a PR would be accepted, just raise a GH issue on the Neo4j repo with the changes in a PR.